# Media QUERY - Adjusting Columns and Rows HTML

Tags: html, css, media-queries

i created a gallery using HTML consists of one row includes three columns as shown in the [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFP3E.jpg) then i tried to start my media query second and third columns are OK  but i have a problem that in the first column consists of 6 pics and i want to make 2 pictures per row and when i make `wrap` i got that [shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa4mC.jpg) .

so please if anyone can tell me what shall i add to my code to adjust the gallery in the media query and below is the code i tried to simplify it so you can read it fast... am new here to the group so please excuse my writing and explaining the problem.
thanks in advance for your support.

```css
/* Break Point 2 */


/* for small screens*/

@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {
  /* projects */
  #galleryTab {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 8px;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  #col1 {
    max-width: 52%;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  #col2 {
    max-width: 52%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Start Projects here -->

<div class="row">

  <!-- First Column -->
  <div class="column" id="col1">

    <!-- 1-  -->
    <div class="container class1" style="position: relative; width: 100%;">
      <a class="fancybox" href="images/projects/1_saif1/s11.jpg" data-group="gallery" data-filter="vil" rel="vil1" title="Private Villa (G+1)"><img src="images/projects/thumbnails/1.jpg" width="380" height="239" alt="" /></a>
    </div>

    <!-- 2- -->
    <div class="container class1" style="position: relative; width: 100%">
      <a class="fancybox" href="images/projects/2_dic/dic1.jpg" data-group="gallery" data-filter="ware" rel="ware1" title="Office and Open Shed"><img src="images/projects/thumbnails/2.jpg" width="380" height="239" alt="" /></a>
    </div>

    <!-- 3-  -->
    <div class="container class1" style="position: relative; width: 100%">
      <a class="fancybox" href="images/projects/3_sharjah_sport/rec1.jpg" data-group="gallery" data-filter="int" rel="int1" title="Sharjah Sports Club"><img src="images/projects/thumbnails/3.jpg" width="380" height="239" alt="" /></a>
    </div>

    <!-- 4- -->
    <div class="container class1" style="position: relative; width: 100%">
      <a class="fancybox" href="images/projects/4_saif2/s21.jpg" data-group="gallery" data-filter="vil" rel="vil2" title="G+1 Private Villa"><img src="images/projects/thumbnails/4.jpg" width="380" height="239" alt="" /></a>
    </div>

    <!-- 5- -->
    <div class="container class1" style="position: relative; width: 100%">
      <a class="fancybox" href="images/projects/5_jarwan/j1.jpg" data-group="gallery" data-filter="vil" rel="vil3" title="G+1 Private Villa"><img src="images/projects/thumbnails/5.jpg" width="380" height="239" alt="" /></a>
    </div>

    <!-- 6-  -->
    <div class="container class1" style="position: relative; width: 100%">
      <a class="fancybox" href="images/projects/6_soccer_school/soccer1.jpg" data-group="gallery" data-filter="res" rel="res1" title="Soccer School Sharjah"><img src="images/projects/thumbnails/6.jpg" width="380" height="239" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <!-- End of First Column -->


    <!-- Second Column -->
    <div class="column" id="col2">

      <!-- 7-  -->
      <div class="container class1" style="position: relative; width: 100%">
        <a class="fancybox" href="images/projects/7_shrajah_retail/retail1.jpg" data-group="gallery" data-filter="res" rel="res2" title="Sharjah Retail"><img src="images/projects/thumbnails/7.jpg" width="380" height="239" alt="" /></a>
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="text">Sharjah Retail</div>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden">
          <a class="fancybox" href="images/projects/7_shrajah_retail/retail2.jpg" rel="res2"><img src="images/projects/7_shrajah_retail/retail2.jpg" alt="retails" /></a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- 8- -->
      <div class="container class1" style="position: relative; width: 100%">
        <a class="fancybox" href="images/projects/8_dubailand/dubailand1.jpg" data-group="gallery" data-filter="res" rel="res3" title="G+11 Residential Building"><img src="images/projects/thumbnails/8.jpg" width="380" height="483" alt="" /></a>
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="text">G+11 Residential Building</div>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden">
          <a class="fancybox" href="images/projects/8_dubailand/dubailand2.jpg" rel="res3"><img src="images/projects/8_dubailand/dubailand2.jpg" alt="residential_building" /></a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- 9-  -->
      <div class="container class1" style="position: relative; width: 100%">
        <a class="fancybox" href="images/projects/9_sharjah_shops/shops1.jpg" data-group="gallery" data-filter="res" rel="res4" title="Sharjah Shops"><img src="images/projects/thumbnails/9.jpg" width="380" height="239" alt="" /></a>
      </div>

      <!-- 10-  -->
      <div class="container class1" style="position: relative; width: 100%">
        <a class="fancybox" href="images/projects/10_shrjah_hotel/h1.jpg" data-group="gallery" data-filter="int" rel="int2" title="Hotel Interior Design"><img src="images/projects/thumbnails/10.jpg" width="380" height="239" alt="" /></a>
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="text">Hotel Interior Design</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- 11- -->
      <div class="container class1" style="position: relative; width: 100%">
        <a class="fancybox" href="images/projects/11_swidi/sw1.jpg" data-group="gallery" data-filter="vil" rel="vil4" title="Ground Only Private Villa"><img src="images/projects/thumbnails/11.jpg" width="380" height="239" alt="" /></a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- End of Second Column -->


    <!-- Third Column -->
    <div class="column" id="col3">

      <!-- 12-  -->
      <div class="container class1" style="position: relative; width: 100%">
        <a class="fancybox" href="images/projects/12_alhamadi/hama1.jpg" data-group="gallery" data-filter="vil" rel="vil5" title="Private Villa (G+1)"><img src="images/projects/thumbnails/12.jpg" alt="" width="380" height="239" id="h1016" /></a>
      </div>

      <!-- 13-  -->
      <div class="container class1" style="position: relative; width: 100%">
        <a class="fancybox" href="images/projects/13_ali/ali1.jpg" data-group="gallery" data-filter="vil" rel="vil6" title="Private Villa (B+G+1)"><img src="images/projects/thumbnails/13.jpg" width="380" height="239" alt="" /></a>
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="text">Private Villa (B+G+1)</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- 14- -->
      <div class="container class1" style="position: relative; width: 100%">
        <a class="fancybox" href="images/projects/14_alowais/living1.jpg" data-group="gallery" data-filter="int" rel="int3" title="Private Villa Interior Design"><img src="images/projects/thumbnails/14.jpg" width="380" height="239" alt="" /></a>
      </div>

      <!-- 15- -->
      <div class="container class1" style="position: relative; width: 100%">
        <a class="fancybox" href="images/projects/15_ajman/Ajman1.jpg" data-group="gallery" data-filter="res" rel="res5" title="G +8 Pdoium +22 Typ. Residential Building"><img src="images/projects/thumbnails/15.jpg" width="380" height="727" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Third Column -->


  </div>
  <!-- Row End here and Projects as well -->
```